# gpg signing and encrypting using my private key and end users public key

Tags: vb.net, pgp, gnupg

Currently we use Kleopatra to Sign and Encrypt files sent to a third party. We sign with our private key and encrypt with our public key and the third party's public key...

Using gpg by itself, do I make multiple calls adding each piece as i go? i.e.:

```
gpg.BinaryPath = (path to GnuPG)
gpg.Recipient = myUserID
gpg.Passphrase = myPassword
gpg.Sign( origfile, signedfile )
gpg.Encrypt( signedFile, signedAndEncryptedFile )
gpg.Recipient = thirdPartyUserID
gpg.Encrypt( signedAndEncryptedFile , thirdPartySignedAndEncryptedFile )
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Are you asking about using `gpg` from the command line or from a program or script in some language? If the latter, what language is that supposed to be?

Comment: I'm trying to use GnuGP from within my own .Net program. The program has access to the functions you see above. Generally what I am asking, however, is do I need to make multiple calls like I have shown above to get what I get by using the GUI Kleopatra?

Comment: Please add tags to indicate what *language* you're using. (I don't see a tag for .net itself, which seems odd.)